# Facebook connector: login issues

Tags: facebook

I am using a development environment http://localhost:3000 how can i install the SSL certificate in local?it doesn't make sense. How come Facebook force me to use https, does exist a sandbox or other way around?

thanks in advance

Comment: Per https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/, "You will still be able to use HTTP with “localhost” addresses, but only while your app is still in development mode."

Comment: (If you can't put your main app in developer mode, you can create a "test app" attached to the main one. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/)

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote me and it works thank you so much

Comment: Ah! You're welcome, glad it helped.